# Ionic 2 Android build is broken, even though in Ionic View and on Ionic Serve it works fine

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic2

I build an Ionic app that utilizes Ionic Native's geolocation and camera.  I don't know how to debug this though.  I'm on Cordova 6.4.0 and ionic-angular 2.0.0-rc4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted this question too hastily.  Turns out I had not installed the android cordova-plugin-geolocation.